# Get storage account access keys from Azure Resource Manager to make storage calls authentication failed

Tags: azure

After getting access token, i run this below command but i got authentication error shown in fig attached.

```
$keysResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION-ID/resourceGroups/RESOURCE-GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/STORAGE-ACCOUNT/listKeys/?api-version=2016-12-01
    -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $ARMToken"}
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

this means you do not have enough permissions to perform that action. ask your administrator to grant you permissions (easiest way - assign contributor role on the storage account).